# Check for number of javascript operations to keep them below a limit on a server side execution

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, rhino, serverside-javascript

i need to check if my script exceeds a maximum operations limit. This limit is set to 2000 operations per script(Rhino server side execution).

I would like to know how to count the number of operations in general for a js file or for this specific code snippet:

```js
var storeObject = "hillutter,roco".split(',')
var storeObjectLength = storeObject.length;

var maxStoreSize = 10;
var userObject = "{'hillutter':5,'puriutter':10,'roco':10,'bianto':15,'anabelle':15,'puzon':15}"
var checkUserObjectLength = userObject.split(',').length;
userObject = JSON.parse(userObject.replace(/'/g,'"'));
maxStoreSize = maxStoreSize-storeObjectLength-1;

if(checkUserObjectLength>=maxStoreSize){ //if size greater than X entries, reduce to 
    var userSortArray = [];
    var plainObject = {}; //new sorted plain array
    var checkUserObject = Object.keys(userObject);
    for (var i = 0; i < maxStoreSize; i++) {
        var key = checkUserObject[i];
        userSortArray.push({storeStorageValue2: key, score: userObject[key]});
    }
    userSortArray.sort(function (a,b){ return b.score - a.score}); //sort
    userSortArray.filter(function(ele,i){ 
        if(i<(maxStoreSize-storeObjectLength)){ // max count minus parameter length
            plainObject[""+ele.storeStorageValue2+""] = ele.score 
        } 
    }); 
    userObject = plainObject;
}

console.log(userObject)
```

Else, what could be improved to reduce operations. I think the filter-loop can be combined within the sort-loop. But i don't know how with this associative array. I've tried it with an "real" array but run into the max. operations limit, with this associative array i can skip at least on loop.
**Goal** is to cut off the *userObject* to the *maxStoreSize* but keep a sorted output by score.

Comment: Is what you're saying that you're using this in a Rhino-based environment and Rhino is telling you it's over 2,000? Or are you asking how to count them with Rhino? Or both?

Comment: Both, I'm in a Rhino env with a limit. To prevent to run against this limit I would like to count before deploy. The main solution I'm looking for is how to calculate the operations because the limit is calculated by rules e.g. "a function call costs 100 operations"

Comment: What version of Rhino?

Comment: Don't have an exact version number but very old ~2006 so maybe 1.6?

Comment: do you have access to the server? Can you get the Rhino JAR file?

Comment: No, not possible